# Dark matter and black hole

Tags: black-holes, dark-matter

Is black hole a kind of dark matter.

Comment: Have you read the Wikipedia entries on [Black Holes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole) and [Dark Matter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter)? Doing so would enlighten you on why your question is wrong.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows insufficient prior research, and it is a duplicate in that it may be answered by any SE questions' answer which addresses what a black hole is.

Answer (score 2):

http://t.space.com/all/25691-dark-matter-black-hole-atoms

Some people much smarter than me think that "quantum" sized black holes are a candidate for dark matter. There are problems with it, but as far as I know there are problems with every candidate so far. I'm just reporting what I have read.

My understanding of "dark matter" (meaning 1) is that it is sometimes used as a placeholder for invisible contributions of mass to the universe. I have seen even normal black holes be included under this definition. Traditional black holes are sort of like "known unknowns", in this equation, that can't be the whole equation, which requires extra "unknown unknowns" (apologies to Donald Rumsfeld).

"Dark matter" (meaning 2) is alternatively used to refer to a theoretical particle which will hopefully account for the majority of this "unknown unknown" contribution to general "dark matter" (meaning 1).

From my very limited understanding, this theoretical particle seems to form a halo around galaxies, which is why the supermassive black holes at the centre of galaxies are not a good candidate.

I have heard of other theories for "dark matter"(1) which does not include "Dark matter"(2), and I am not able to even begin to evaluate the viability of any of them.